# How to create two relations one-to-zero between two tables in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables that are related by one-to-one. Main table *Message*.

```
public class Message
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    //Other fields
    public virtual MessageContent MessageContent {get;set;}
}
```

And related table *MessageContent*:

```
public class MessageContent
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey]
    public Guid MessageId {get; set;}
    //Other fields
    public virtual Message Message {get;set;}
}
```

It works well. But I need to add two more relationships one-to-zero from *MessageContent* to *Message*:

```
public class MessageContent
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey]
    public Guid MessageId {get; set;}
    //Other fields
    public virtual Message Message {get;set;}

    public virtual Message Reason {get;set;}
    public Guid? ReasonId {get;set;}

    public virtual Message Report {get;set;}
    public Guid? ReportId {get;set;}
}
```

Throw exception. How add two relationships one-to-zero from related table to main table?

Comment: What's the exception that is thrown? Is this code-first?

Comment: Yes, Its code-first. if use DataAnnotation way described in the answer below, an exception is thrown: Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not specifying the foreignkeys for `Reason` and `Report` now. You'll need to change your `MessageContent` like this:

```
public class MessageContent
{
[Key]
[ForeignKey("Message")]
public Guid MessageId {get; set;}
//Other fields
public virtual Message Message {get;set;}

[ForeignKey("Reason")]
public Guid? ReasonId {get;set;}
public virtual Message Reason {get;set;}

[ForeignKey("Report")]
public Guid? ReportId {get;set;}
public virtual Message Report {get;set;}
}
```

Or you can do it through fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MessageContent>()
            .HasOptional(m => m.Reason)
            .WithRequired(r => r.MessageContent)
            .HasForeignKey("ReportId");
```

**Edit:** The error you're getting is because you have a circular reference between `Message` and `MessageContent`. The easiest way would be to make `MessageId` in `MessageContent` nullable and create another primary key for `MessageContent`. This would make your relationship optional. The second solution is to tell EF in fluent api which model is the principal and which one is the dependent entity. Now both `MessageContent` and `Message` are seen as principal and EF doesn't know which one to insert/update first when you call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: if use DataAnnotation, an exception is thrown: Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

Comment: The exception that is thrown when the SaveChanges method is called

Comment: If use Fluent API - Compiler Error CS1061: ForeignKeyNavigationPropertyConfiguration does not contain a definition for HasPrimaryKey and no extension method HasPrimaryKey accepting a first argument of type ForeignKeyNavigationPropertyConfiguration could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: @chuk.huck Editing my answer

Comment: @chuk.huck Remember to accept/vote up an answer if it resolved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not annotated your ReasonId and ReportId parameters with the ForeignKey attribute as you have with MessageId. Have you tried specifying that attribute?

In general, you are relying here on "minimal configuration" with EF determining that, for example, the MessageId key is associated with the Message property and not the Reason property. While this can work, it can make it difficult to detect when things go wrong or when you've passed the line of what EF can infer.

Often, being more explicit can help. For example:

- Fill in the constructor parameter on ForeignKey
- Use fluent configuration to fully specify the properties, e. g.

```
    builder.Entity().HasOptional(mc => mc.Reason)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(mc => mc.ReasonId);
```